# Replace pandas dataframe columns with another dataframe based on specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with many columns df1, df2, and i want to replace all df1 values (except the time columns) with the data from df2 columns where the time values is the same:

```
df1:

index time   x y   ......many other columns ( the same as df2)
0       1    1 1
1       1.1  2 2
2       1.1  3 3
3       1.1  4 4
4       1.4  5 5
5       1.5  6 6
6       1.5  7 7


df2:

index time  x   y   ....many other columns (the same as df1)
0       1   10  10
1       1.1 11  11
2       1.2 12  12
3       1.3 13  13
4       1.4 14  14
5       1.5 15  15
6       1.6 16  16



the result for df1 should be:

index time  x   y   ....many other columns 
0       1    10 10
1       1.1  11 11
2       1.1  11 11
3       1.1  11 11
4       1.4  14 14
5       1.5  15 15
6       1.5  15 15
```

Comment: You could just join the two data frames and drop the first data frame columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was able to get my thinking in order and hopefully have reached a solution that will work for you.

Try this, you can get your answer with using `combine_first`, and doing some tweaking:

1. `combine_first` fills null values from another `dataframe`, so first you can replace all values (except in 'time' column) with `np.nan`. Note that I use 'time' column as the `index`.
2. As `combine_first` will return the union of the two dataframes, you can use `isin` to get only the time values from `df1` in your final output.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1[df1.columns.difference(['time'])] = np.nan
res = df1.set_index('time').combine_first(df2.set_index('time')).reset_index()
li = [i for i in df1['time'].unique()]

final= res[res['time'].isin(li)]
```

Which will get you:

```
   time     x     y
0   1.0  10.0  10.0
1   1.1  11.0  11.0
2   1.1  11.0  11.0
3   1.1  11.0  11.0
6   1.4  14.0  14.0
7   1.5  15.0  15.0
8   1.5  15.0  15.0
```

Try it on your actual dataset, and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to merge:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, left_index = True, right_index = True)
```

then you need to remove the columns you do not need

Comment: wouldn't this thrown an error? when we do df1['time'] we'll get a series, and then call "merge" which is a dataframe attribute

Comment: the problem with merge is that it creates those extra columns with _x, _y suffixes

Comment: Not a problem. Helps you distinguish between the origin of similar col names

Comment: Unfortunately it is a problem for me :( ,those suffixes will create problems in other parts of the program

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Misread the question the first time.  This should help:

```
df1[['time']].merge(df2, on='time')
```

Comment: Won't work, it will remove the duplicate time values from df1 (1.1, 1.1, 1.1 ) and will also add values that are not in df1 ( for example it will add 1.6 time that doesnt exists in df1)

Comment: @Tenshi  Do you understand the code I posted?  I appears as though you may not.

Comment: you're welcome to try your code with the input data that I posted in the question, you'll see it wont give the desired result